# Go to the next page after logging in

Tags: flutter, dart

how to add validation in login proces, so that it takes us to another page only after a positive login ?, now I have done so that you can go to another page after clicking 'log in' even if the data is incorrect :(

api:

```
Future<bool> loginUser(String email, password) async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    };
    var jsonResponse = null;
    final response = await client.post(
      '$baseUrl/user/login',
      // headers: {"content-type":"application/json"},
      body: data
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      sharedPreferences.setInt("id", jsonResponse['id']);
      sharedPreferences.setString("firstName", jsonResponse['firstName']);
      sharedPreferences.setString("lastName", jsonResponse['lastName']);

      return true;
    }else return false;

  }
```

ui:

```
  Container buttonSection() {
    return Container(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height:55.0,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                userApiService.loginUser(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
            }
            Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          },
          child: Text("LOGIN", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
          color: Colors.orange,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61266879/12386821

Answer (score 0):

```
    Future<bool>loginUser(String email, password) async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    };
    var jsonResponse = null;
    final response = await client.post(
      '$baseUrl/user/login',
      // headers: {"content-type":"application/json"},
      body: data
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      sharedPreferences.setInt("id", jsonResponse['id']);
      sharedPreferences.setString("firstName", jsonResponse['firstName']);
      sharedPreferences.setString("lastName", jsonResponse['lastName']);
      navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home()),
      ModalRoute.withName('/'),);
      //IF RESPONSE STATUS CODE = 200, ONLY THEN NAVIGATE TO THE PAGE YOU WANT
      return true;
    }
    else{
    //DO SOMETHING IF FALSE
    return false;
    }
  }
```

```
Container buttonSection() {
    return Container(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height:55.0,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                userApiService.loginUser(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
            }
          },
          child: Text("LOGIN", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
          color: Colors.orange,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare one bool variable like

```
bool loggedIn = false
```

then use it in onPressed event of RaisedButton

```
onPressed: () {
            if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
              loggedIn =  userApiService.loginUser(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
              if(loggedIn){
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
             }else{
              // handle else statement also
             }
            }
          },
```

because loginUser method returns boolean value so we can use that value to check if user inputs true email and password or not.

Comment: I can't because yor answer is incompleted

Comment: what is the problem with my answer please explain it

Comment: before ```userApiService.loginUser...``` must be ```await```, and ```onPressed: ()  async {```